# Creating Stack bar chart in Spotfire

Tags: bar-chart, spotfire

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnbGm.png)I want to create a stack bar chart in spotfire with only 1 column of data. 
So column name is WORK DONE  and the values are YES -10, NO-5, NA - 2

I want to create a stack bar chart in which there will be just one bar colored by different values (yes, no, NA)

But when i am creating the same , i get 3 separate bars ; one for yes, no and NA each.

Is it possible to create such stack bar in spotfire. Please help me in the same.
Thanks in advance.

If not bar chart then maybe some other chart in which i will get a stacked bar?

AP

Comment: Show us what you tried so far.

Comment: Hi @SteveFest , than ks for response. I am unable to attach my file here. please help

Comment: What file do you mean?

Comment: my spotfire file. i am unable to show you what i have done.

Comment: Do you mean by the code?

Comment: i have created a bar chart in spotfire. i am using version 7.6. but i am only getting 3 diff. bars. i want 1 bar only colored by yes , no and NA values

Comment: Is a spotfire file an image or code?

Comment: its an image, not a code

Comment: You could add the image into the post by: clicking the edit button. And press the image button in the edit page.

Comment: done, thanks. I was trying to add image in answers to your comments :)

Comment: @SteveFest any suggestions on the same?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the 'Appearance' tab of the barchart properties and select 'Stacked bars' under the Layout.

When basing your stacked bar on only one column, clear the 'Columns' field under the 'X-axis' tab. In this case you do not want anything to be depicted in at the X-axis, only one stacked bar with the different values.

Please read [this page](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sfire-bauthor/7.8.0/doc/html/en-US/GUID-3BCEF3C7-6670-4D1F-A030-512FF888A835.html) for more information about stacked bars in Spotfire.

On [this page](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.0/doc/html/bar/bar_properties_appearance.htm) you can find more information about the options on bar charts.

Comment: Hi @MarliesV Thanks for the answer. Its not working in my case. I am getting 3 bars instead of 1 stack bar. I think i have to use some aggregation or custom expression on vakue axes which i dnt know. please help if you can .

Comment: Hi @user8165644, I updated my answer with an answer more specific for your case.